# How to change a position of an object in 2D Array

Tags: java, inheritance

Okay i'm making a 2D map array.  It has foxs and hares in it.  They can move around and die. I store the foxes and hares in an arraylist to keep track of how many are left.  My question is how am i able to switch the position of my fox or hare on the array.  Every turn the foxs and hares have to move one spot adjacent to their previous spot.
Heres my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Map {

        protected int numberOfRows; // number of rows in my map
        protected int numberOfColumns; // number of columns in my map
        protected int randomRow;
        protected int randomColumn;
        protected ArrayList<Fox> fox = new ArrayList<Fox>();
        protected ArrayList<Hare> hare = new ArrayList<Hare>();

        Animal map [][]; // creates an instance of my map

        public Map(int rows, int columns)  { // creates a constructor 
            numberOfRows = rows; 
            numberOfColumns = columns;
            map= new Animal[rows][columns]; // puts my number of rows and columns in array
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)  {
                for(int k = 0; k < columns; k++)  {
                    map[i][k] = new Animal(); // feels my map with null
                }
            }
            generateFoxAndHares();
        }

        public void print()  {
            // nested for loop to print my map
            for(int i =0; i < numberOfRows; i++)  {
                for(int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)  {
                    System.out.print(map[i][j].getDisplayChar());
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }


        public void generateFoxAndHares()  {
            int ranRow; // random row for hare or fox to go
            int ranCol; // random column for hare or fox to go
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in); // take user input
            int counter = 1; // counts how many times my while loop runs

            Random r = new Random();

            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)  { // puts foxs on my map
                ranRow = r.nextInt(this.numberOfRows);
                ranCol = r.nextInt(this.numberOfColumns);
                fox.add(new Fox(ranRow, ranCol));
                map[ranRow][ranCol] = fox.get(i);

            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)  { // puts hares on map
                ranRow = r.nextInt(this.numberOfRows);
                ranCol = r.nextInt(this.numberOfColumns);
                hare.add(new Hare(ranRow, ranCol));
                map[ranRow][ranCol] = hare.get(i);
            }

            print();
            System.out.println("Day:  0, Foxs: " + fox.size() + ", Hares:  " + hare.size());


            while(hare.size() > 0 || fox.size() > 0)  { // keeps running
                System.out.println("Press any button to continue");
                String textString;
                textString = myScanner.nextLine();
                print();
                System.out.println("Day:  " + counter + ", Foxs: " + fox.size() + ", Hares:  " + hare.size());
                counter++;

            }
        }
}

public class Animal {
    protected char displayChar;
    protected int xCord;
    protected int yCord;

    public char getDisplayChar()  {
        return displayChar;
    }

    public char getSymbol()  {

          return getDisplayChar();  
    }

    public int getxCord()  {
        return xCord;
    }

    public int getyCord()  {
        return yCord;
    }

}

public class Fox extends Animal{
    public Fox(int x, int y)   {
        this.xCord = x;
        this.yCord = y;
        this.displayChar = 'F';
    }
}

public class Hare extends Animal{

    public Hare(int x, int y)  {
        this.xCord = x;
        this.yCord = y;
        this.displayChar = 'H';
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FoxAndHaresMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map1 = new Map(20,20);
        map1.generateFoxAndHares();

    }
}
```

Heres my Output:

```
FF      H    H       
   F H         F       
        HF           
 F  H             F  
     F  H        F  
          F      F   
 F     HH H          
       H         H  
 HF      HH      F    
 H       H       F   
Day: 0, Hares: 15, Foxes: 15
```

Comment: It seems your animals are immutable, so you should recreate them based on their new position. You need to find an algorithm how you want them to move. (Random in the 4 possible directions? What about the borders?)

Comment: Why are the animals storing their coordinates at all? (Just asking, seems like they are not really needed). It it valid to assume that they mave not on occupied fields? (A fox moving on a field that is occupied by a hare would make sense ... the other ones... not so much)

Comment: Wait, why are you creating Foxes and Hares with (ranRow, ranCol), which you never place on the map? The ones that go on the map always only have coordinates of (0, 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you know that there is a fox at position (3, 7) and you want to move it to (3, 8). You could do this:

```
map[3][7] = new Animal();
map[3][8] = new Fox(3, 8);
```

This would fill the position previously occupied by the fox with an Animal (which is how you were initializing your map, so I assume that is what you want when neither a fox nor a hare is present in that location), and it "moves" the Fox (actually, creates a new one, since your animals know their coordinates, and thus a Fox or Hare object is only valid for one spot on the map) to the new position.

It does seem strange that the animals contain their current coordinates. It may be something you want to reconsider in your design, but it's hard to tell.

I just noticed that your `fox1` and `hare1` objects, which are created in the loops where you place the animals on the map, are never actually used. They will just be garbage collected, and the ones with coordinates (0, 0) from the ArrayLists are the only ones that are placed on the map. This is almost certainly a bug in your current code. Either the coordinates aren't needed in the animals, or the wrong objects are being placed on the map.

Comment: Okay so i took out the two methods that generated the coordinates (0,0) with ones that now take (ranRow, ranCol) and put them on the map.  How do i get there coordinates so i can update them for the next turn?

Comment: You can get their coordinates by calling their `getxCord()` and `getyCord()` methods, but you can't update them because there are no setters for the coordinates. The objects are immutable. You have to either add setters to make them mutable, or you have to create new objects with the new coordinates, or you have to change your design so that the animals don't know their coordinates.